# include sql query in function

Tags: php, sql

I have spent many days on this problem but I couldn't fix it, and am looking for help.
Lets say I have this php-sql:

```
$sql2= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jos_comprofiler WHERE id = ".$userid."");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2) ;
$bdate= $row2['cb_birthday']; // 2012-03-01 year/month/day
```

and this function:

```
function _weeks($date) { 
  global $bdate ;
  $month = substr($date, 0, 2) ;
  $day = substr($date, 3, 2);
  $year = substr($date, 6, 4) ;
  $bmonth = substr($bdate, 5, 2) ;
  $bday = substr($bdate, 8, 2);
  $byear = substr($bdate, 0, 4) ;
  $birthday = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, $bmonth, $bday, $byear);
  $eventdate = gmmktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);

  $weeknumber = (int)(($eventdate - $birthday) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)) + 1 ;
  return $weeknumber ;
}
```

and i have 10 submit buttoms to submit dates

```
if (isset($_POST['submit0'])){
  if ($userid !=0 ){
    $date0 = $_POST['date0'];
    $func_date= _weeks($date0);
    mysql_query(" UPDATE data SET w_dd = '".$func_date."' WHERE id_user= '".$userid."' ");
    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT id_user FROM data WHERE id_user='".$userid."' ");
    $result= mysql_num_rows($sql);
    mysql_query(" UPDATE data SET dd = '".$date0."' WHERE id_user= '".$userid."' ");
  }

  if (isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    if ($userid !=0 ){
      $date1 = $_POST['date1'];
      $func_date= _weeks($date1);
      mysql_query(" UPDATE data SET w_dd = '".$func_date."' WHERE id_user= '".$userid."' ");
      $sql= mysql_query("SELECT id_user FROM data WHERE id_user='".$userid."' ");
      $result= mysql_num_rows($sql);
      mysql_query(" UPDATE data SET dd = '".$date1."' WHERE id_user= '".$userid."' ");
    }
```

...and so on till submit9 button.

The problem is `$bdate` in the function , it doesn't work `$bdate` like that, but if I try to make a specific date like below, it works like a charm the `$func_date`.

```
function _weeks($date){
  $bdate = "2012-03-01";
```

I even put the `$bdate` inside function but that didn't work either.
How can I make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Can you echo $bdate and see whether the date format is okay?

Comment: if i echo $bdate alone without function , its echoing the date normal its good.

Comment: echo it inside the function call so you can see what value it gets

Comment: You should also really pass in `$bdate` to the function as an argument as well. `global` is evil in almost all cases.

Comment: can you explain litle prodigitalson ?

Comment: you have `global $bdate` at the top of you function definition. you should pass it in as an argument instead of relying on a variable that can be changed from outside. If the function works to generate `$bdate` then you shouldnt be declaring it like that you should be assigning a value... and then you shoudl return it from the function instead of assuming the function will set a global value. Generally speaking functions should be a black box you pass in arguments and get back a value.

Comment: :( i have difficult to understand you . can you write the code how you mean prodigitalson ? and i will try it

Comment: While it's not specifically answering the question, can I add that the practice here of injecting $_POST values directly into a MySQL query without any form of sanitization is an absolute security nightmare.  All a hacker would have to do is send some specially formatted strings to your code and they will have complete access to your (or your client's) database.  Just a heads up.  Carry on.

Comment: of course you can tell me how to protect my database from injecting alex .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$userid = ""; // Nuot sure where this is form ;
$date = "";
$mysql = new mysqli ( "localhost", "root", "", "db" );

if ($mysql->connect_errno) {
    printf ( "Connect failed: %s\n", $mysql->connect_error );
    exit ();
}

$result = $mysql->query ( sprintf ( "SELECT cb_birthday FROM jos_comprofiler id = '%s'", $userid ) );

if (! $result) {
    die ( "Error Runing jos_comprofiler query" );
}

$josProfile = $result->fetch_assoc ();

$_POST ["date0"] = "03/22/2012 "; // Sample
$_POST ["submit0"] = "oK"; // Sample

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    if (! isset ( $_POST ["submit$i"] ) || ! isset ( $_POST ["date$i"] )) {
        continue;
    }
    $date = $_POST ["date$i"];
    $weekNumber = weekNumber ( $josProfile ['cb_birthday'], $date );
    if ($userid != 0) {
        $this->query ( sprintf ( "UPDATE data SET w_dd = '%s' ,  dd = '%s'  WHERE id_user= '%s' ", $weekNumber, $date, $userid ) );
    }
}

function weekNumber($birthDay,$postDate) {
    $postDate = trim($postDate);
    $birthDay = trim($birthDay);
    $postDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $postDate);
    $birthDay = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $birthDay);
    $sec = (int) $postDate->format("U") - $birthDay->format("U");   
    return ceil($sec / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7));
}
```

You you are having issue with `DateTime::createFromFormat` and `mysqli` you can use

```
$userid = ""; // Nuot sure where this is form ;
$date = "";

$result = mysql_query( sprintf ( "SELECT cb_birthday FROM jos_comprofiler id = '%s'", $userid ) );
$josProfile = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$_POST ["date0"] = "03/22/2012 "; // Sample
$_POST ["submit0"] = "oK"; // Sample

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    if (! isset ( $_POST ["submit$i"] ) || ! isset ( $_POST ["date$i"] )) {
        continue;
    }
    $date = $_POST ["date$i"];
    $weekNumber = weekNumber ( $josProfile ['cb_birthday'], $date );
    if ($userid != 0) {
       mysql_query( sprintf ( "UPDATE data SET w_dd = '%s' ,  dd = '%s'  WHERE id_user= '%s' ", $weekNumber, $date, $userid ) );
    }
}




function weekNumber($birthDay, $postDate) {
    $postDate = trim ( $postDate );
    $birthDay = trim ( $birthDay );

    list($postMonth,$postD,$postYear) = explode("/", $postDate);
    list($birthYear,$birthMonth,$birthD) = explode("-", $birthDay);

    $postTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $postMonth, $postD, $postYear);
    $birthTime =  mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthMonth, $birthD, $birthYear);

    $sec = ( int )$postTime - $birthTime;
    return ceil ( $sec / (60 * 60 * 24 * 7) );
}
```

Let me know if you have any additional issues

Comment: i want calculate number of weeks ($weeknumber) when date is submitted ._weeks is just a name of function. if user submit a date , this function will calculate the number of weeks from this date and then store it in database ($func_date), i just want say that i have many dates to be submitted as shown up from date0 to date9

Comment: One clarification ... when you mean ` the number of weeks from this date ` do you mean week number form that date till now .. or week number of the current date in the year

Comment: thx for trying . week number i mean between his birthday and the date of this submitting. $date (which he submitt) -  $birthday

Comment: Cool  .. sorry i question is too much .... also clarify .. are you calculating week number since he was born ? or just the current year .. (If its the current .. year .. what if his birthday has passed ?? )

Comment: its this in my code up         $weeknumber = (int)(($eventdate - $birthday) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)) + 1 ;

Comment: the calculation is how many weeks between his born and the date which he submitted , i have this variable up in the code  `$weeknumber`

Comment: this code `UPDATE data SET w_dd` i have 10 rows names , every one is updated by its own. this w_dd just one . i need others also to be updated . if user submit date0 the w_dd will update if he submit date1 the w_dd will update etc

Comment: You can add as may rows names as possible .. what i used was was http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php ... you can replace with with yours ... then i also  use `for loop` so that you don't have to duplicate your code 10 times ...

Comment: Cool  .. glad i could help .. please note that i was working on the date format you gave me .. you can change it what every you want ..

Comment: you wrote `$date = "";` what should be the date here ?

Comment: nothing  .. i was just declaring my date ... you would see ` $date = $_POST ["date$i"];` in the later part of the code

Comment: it comes this error `Call to undefined function query()`  from `$result = query ( sprintf ( "SELECT cb_birthday FROM jos_comprofiler id = '%s'", $userid ) );` . obs i have changed this result because i didnt want write database password and name and root ...

Comment: it is `$result  = $mysql->query` not `$result = query` .... look at my code properly before making your changes

Comment: yes i have make it like what you wrote but it saids `call to undefined function query()`.   and there is also error `Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat()` in the function ,i think my page didnt accet classes , so better without classes to work

Comment: Ig you have PHP 5.3 DateTime  should be supported ........ I whould update the code to narrow mysql error

Comment: same error `Call to a member function query() on a non-object in `  `$result = $mysql->query ( sprintf ( "SELECT cb_birthday FROM jos_comprofiler id = '%s'", $userid ) );`

Comment: Just updated my code .. you shoul dnot have that error if you have `mysqli` installed ... but this can be easy changed to the only `mysql` lib

Comment: :( , i dont know it comes again those errors 1- `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in` 2-`mktime() expects parameter 6 to be long, string given in`

Comment: There is definitely something you are doing wrong ... have created 2 different version  .. have tested it locally and it works fine ... You need to take your time and look at the code before you make modification

Comment: ok :)  now i understand your code and it works very good now :) , thanks so much

Comment: You are welcome ... am glad i was able you help you at last .... longest request have spent time on